# When is the Bitcoin payout for solving a block going to change?

Tags: mining-reward, reward-schedule

When is the Bitcoin payout for solving a block going to change?  What happens when overnight it is half as profitable to process a block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It halves from 50BTC to 25BTC block reward after 210,000 blocks, which at 6 blocks mined per hour by my calculations works out to be in 358 days, which is around **Dec 13th, 2012**.

It's likely that the number of active miners will reduce substantially at that point, but within a relatively short time the difficulty should adjust down so that approx 6 blocks per hour are mined again. In the time it takes this to happen, transactions may take somewhat longer to be processed and confirmed.

Comment: +1 - and isn't it nice to know well in advance when the conditions of your business are going to change so you can start a gentle ramp up of alternatives?

Comment: around Dec 13th, 2012: Did not the Mayas predict something like that? :-)

Comment: That's Dec 21st, according to Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_calendar . Oh, and apparently: "for the ancient Maya, it was a huge celebration to make it to the end of a whole cycle". I need to start planning my block-reward-halving party!